# Error in cor(mydata) : 'x' must be numeric

Tags: r, matrix, correlation

In R, I have been having trouble trying to create a correlation matrix for my data. I keep running into this problem: "Error in cor(mydata) : 'x' must be numeric"  and I don't know how to fix it.

```
> mydata <- Combo[, c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)]
> head(mydata, 13)

> #computing matrix
> corrmax = cor(mydata)
**Error in cor(mydata) : 'x' must be numeric**
>
```

[image]

Comment: `Site`, `Unemployment` and `Below.Poverty` are not numeric as they have characters hence the error. You could omit these variables, or you could convert the last two to numeric by removing the `%` and converting. You will have to omit the `Site` variable

Comment: ... also you will likely need to deal with the `NA`; see the help page of `?cor` for strategies

Answer (score 3):

I believe not all the data in `mydata` are numeric. You can test this by running: `str(mydata)` or `sapply(mydata, is.numeric)`.

If there are variables in `mydata` that are `chr` or other non-numeric formats or return `FALSE` in the case of `sapply`, you will need to convert them to numeric before running the command or be more selective about the set of variables for which you calculate a correlation. I see strings and percent signs in what you posted. The strings will need to be removed and the formatted percents (%) converted to a numeric representation (decimals).